# How to parse Stripe JSON response after credit card creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, stripe-payments

I want to save a Stripe card_id to my database based on the JSON response. I'm playing with the examples from the Stripe documentation right now:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_3Ek7h52yGbLpQo")
customer.cards.create(:card => {:number => "4242424242424242",
:exp_month => 10, :exp_year => 2014})
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
#<Stripe::Card:0x3ff2f0191540> JSON: {"id":"card_3GHjrJqMgoyTNy","object":"card","last4":"4242","type":"Visa","exp_month":10,"exp_year":2014,"fingerprint":"Ds0FdzrOSdYMkwC0","customer":"cus_3Ek7h52yGbLpQo","country":"US","name":null,"address_line1":null,"address_line2":null,"address_city":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_country":null,"cvc_check":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_zip_check":null}
```

In my controller, after creating the credit card, how can I parse the JSON to get only the card id? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the credit card from the response like this:

```
@card = customer.cards.create(:card => {:number => "4242424242424242",
:exp_month => 10, :exp_year => 2014})

@card.id  #this should have the card id in it
```

Comment: Hi @Dhaulagiri, I think I tried to make things way more complicated than they needed to be! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The value I get from that is a Json string, of which 'foo.id' returns nil.  Not sure if something has changed, but how to actually parse the nested-json and get some of the other fields as well?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code @JosephK.  This code should still apply.  Maybe post a new question with the particulars?