# How to parse Stripe JSON response after Customer.create?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I've read other threads which use this version of the Stripe API, and the question of actually parsing the nested JSON was never answered (ex: [How to parse Stripe JSON response after credit card creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960027/how-to-parse-stripe-json-response-after-credit-card-creation)); or marked as duplicate (ex: [How to read the stripe webhook response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655399/how-to-read-the-stripe-webhook-response)), though the 'orig of the duplicate' is very different, and doesn't give me a clue.

So here is what I've got.  This part works

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :card  => params[:stripeToken],
    :plan => params[:stripe_plan_id],
    :email => current_user.email
  )
```

... and gets me a JSON response which looks like this:

```
"id": "cus_4ab7wXjPrnoBvm",
"object": "customer",
"created": 1408029243,
"livemode": false,
"description": null,
"email": "edsmith@test.com",
"delinquent": false,
"metadata": {},
"subscriptions": {"object":"list","total_count":1,"has_more":false,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_4ab7wXjPrnoBvm/subscriptions","data":[{"id":"sub_4ab7tOTkirRQ8r","plan":{"id":"gold","interval":"month","name":"Gold Plan","created":1408013865,"amount":399,"currency":"usd","object":"plan","livemode":false,"interval_count":1,"trial_period_days":null,"metadata":{},"statement_description":null},"object":"subscription","start":1408029243,"status":"active","customer":"cus_4ab7wXjPrnoBvm","cancel_at_period_end":false,"current_period_start":1408029243,"current_period_end":1410707643,"ended_at":null,"trial_start":null,"trial_end":null,"canceled_at":null,"quantity":1,"application_fee_percent":null,"discount":null,"metadata":{}}]},
"discount": null,
"account_balance": 0,
"currency": "usd",
"cards": {"object":"list","total_count":1,"has_more":false,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_4ab7wXjPrnoBvm/cards","data":[{"id":"card_14RPvP4WgFgXeu1koPs2f9Zd","object":"card","last4":"5904","brand":"Diners Club","funding":"credit","exp_month":2,"exp_year":2015,"fingerprint":"XTb65AiBJVROg4FA","country":null,"name":"edsmith@test.com","address_line1":null,"address_line2":null,"address_city":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_country":null,"cvc_check":"pass","address_line1_check":null,"address_zip_check":null,"customer":"cus_4ab7wXjPrnoBvm"}]},
"default_card": "card_14RPvP4WgFgXeu1koPs2f9Zd"
}
```

So I parse this to a hash with:

```
stripe_customer_params = JSON.parse customer.to_s
```

Which gets this:

```
{"id"=>"cus_4abKeDBM5EGfy6", "object"=>"customer", "created"=>1408030013, "livemode"=>false, "description"=>nil, "email"=>"georgesmith@test.com", "delinquent"=>false, "metadata"=>{}, "subscriptions"=>{
    "object"=>"list", "total_count"=>1, "has_more"=>false, "url"=>"/v1/customers/cus_4abKeDBM5EGfy6/subscriptions", "data"=>[{
        "id"=>"sub_4abKNsI4WqeZYS", "plan"=>{
            "id"=>"gold", "interval"=>"month", "name"=>"Gold Plan", "created"=>1408013865, "amount"=>399, "currency"=>"usd", "object"=>"plan", "livemode"=>false, "interval_count"=>1, "trial_period_days"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}, "statement_description"=>nil
            }, 
            "object"=>"subscription", "start"=>1408030013, "status"=>"active", "customer"=>"cus_4abKeDBM5EGfy6", "cancel_at_period_end"=>false, "current_period_start"=>1408030013, "current_period_end"=>1410708413, "ended_at"=>nil, "trial_start"=>nil, "trial_end"=>nil, "canceled_at"=>nil, "quantity"=>1, "application_fee_percent"=>nil, "discount"=>nil, "metadata"=>{}
        }
    ]}, 
"discount"=>nil, "account_balance"=>0, "currency"=>"usd", "cards"=>{
    "object"=>"list", "total_count"=>1, "has_more"=>false, "url"=>"/v1/customers/cus_4abKeDBM5EGfy6/cards", "data"=>[{
        "id"=>"card_14RQ7p4WgFgXeu1kOETsWaqN", "object"=>"card", "last4"=>"5556", "brand"=>"Visa", "funding"=>"debit", "exp_month"=>4, "exp_year"=>2015, "fingerprint"=>"PDbelzu2DLr2A1C3", "country"=>"US", "name"=>"georgesmith@test.com", "address_line1"=>nil, "address_line2"=>nil, "address_city"=>nil, "address_state"=>nil, "address_zip"=>nil, "address_country"=>nil, "cvc_check"=>"pass", "address_line1_check"=>nil, "address_zip_check"=>nil, "customer"=>"cus_4abKeDBM5EGfy6"
        }]
    }, 
"default_card"=>"card_14RQ7p4WgFgXeu1kOETsWaqN"}
```

But these are nil when inspected:

```
stripe_customer_params[:id]
stripe_customer_params[:cards]
```

The first should get me the id *from the JSON*, and the latter should have a subset of the full-hash.  Where am I going wrong?

------EDIT
Ok, I was so close.  It is that when parsing json to hash, you have to use quotes like this:

```
stripe_customer_params['id']
stripe_customer_params['cards']
```

So now I get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" on this:

```
stripe_customer_params['cards']['data']['last4']
```

The DB field is a string, and the hash value is quoted as a string, so, some bit with the nested array of hashes to figure out still.

--------Edit 2

OK, the answer is:

```
stripe_customer_params['cards']['data'].first['last4']
```

... because 'data' is an array of hashes (though only 1 hash is in it).

-------Edit 3
For clarification as to why I get JSON back, rather than an object; I am using the javascript-generated pop-up form.  The form is generated inline with:

```
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" 
    data-key="pk_test_foo"
    data-label="Submit" 
    data-email="<%=current_user.email%>" 
    data-image="/square-image.png" 
    data-name="mysite.com" 
    data-description="Payment Plan 1" 
    data-amount="1000">
  </script>
```

This creates a button, with text "Submit" (data-label, above).  When clicked, the pop-up form appears.

I have the Ruby-JSON-parsing syntax figured out, so it is working now.  But if there is some other 'data-foo' I can add to get an object back, instead of JSON, that would be good to know for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newbie to parsing JSON - I had missing Quotes around values - should be this:

```
stripe_customer_params['id']
stripe_customer_params['cards']
```

And the 'data' element is an array, so for that one you use:

```
stripe_customer_params['cards']['data'].first['last4']
```

Try the response by Bongs above, first.  Depending on how you implement Stripe, that may work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. I was using the Stripe Checkout and having trouble parsing their response. Here is the solution I used to save specific credit card information:

```
# Create a Customer
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :source => token,
  :plan => "gold",
  :email => @user.email
)

# Grab the response data from Stripe:
card = customer.sources.first


# Save their Stripe ID:
@user.stripe_customer_id = customer.id

# Save their credit card details:
@user.card_id = card.id
@user.card_brand = card.brand
@user.card_last4 = card.last4
@user.card_expiration = Date.new(card.exp_year, card.exp_month, 1)
```

Then, you save it all to your database with a simple:

```
@user.save
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  :card  => params[:stripeToken],
  :plan => params[:stripe_plan_id],
  :email => current_user.email
)
```

And then

```
customer.id # will return id and similarly you can access other attributes
```

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that in the other question I referenced.  I get nil on that. How to parse the JSON is the question?

Comment: Are you using any weird and exotic gems? That should return a Stripe::Customer object, not raw JSON.

Comment: `gem 'stripe'`. Are you creating the customer in view? or are you trying to read the stripe webhook response?

Comment: Yes, that gem.  Reading the response from the code, above, which is the controller-code handling the form submit.  The response is JSON.  With the changes I added in edits, it works now; just a matter of learning how to deal with nested-array-JSON in Ruby.

Comment: Just to clarify, I began with the assumption that I would get a  Stripe::Customer object back.  When it didn't work, I did a puts foo.inspect on it, and found it was JSON.