# Rails & Stripe - Stock shipping address in a var, in the ChargesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

with Stripe on Rails 4, I want to stock the shipping address of my customer in a variable `@testvar`, in my ChargesController, so I can :
- Display it in the charges#create page, as a "Here is where we will deliver"
- Send an email to the admin with this info.

Here is my ChargesController : (**UPDATED 3rd April**)

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create

  admin = Admin.last

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    email: params[:stripeEmail],
    card: params[:stripeToken],
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :currency    => 'eur',
    :receipt_email => params[:stripeEmail],
  )

  customer_name = charge["name"]
  AdminMailer.outfit_ordered(admin, customer_name).deliver_now


rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to :back
end
end
```

**UPDATE 3rd April**
I've added a mailer, hence the two following line

```
  customer_name = charge["name"]
  AdminMailer.outfit_ordered(admin, customer_name).deliver_now
```

I've found the following part in [another aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315765/how-to-parse-stripe-json-response-after-customer-create), but I can't get it to work.

```
stripe_customer_params = JSON.parse customer.to_s
@testvar = stripe_customer_params['cards']['data'].first['shipping_address']
```

Furthermore, when I assign a random value to my @testvar (like `@testvar = "test"`) and display it in my charges#create view, it works... But @testvar keeps this value with the other tests I run after that.

I am stuck with this problem and can't find anything that helps me in the Stripe's API documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It that your full ChargesController?  If not, please post in full.

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer, I've updated my ChargesController. I've tried getting the customer's name with charge["name"], but I tried displaying it in my charges#create view and it doesn't work.

Comment: In your view you've got the Stripe JS inside of a form, correct?  When you add other fields inside that form, they will get submitted to the action of the form after Stripe constructs its token.
If you’ve got the shipping address fields inside of this form, they will get sent to your controller action.

Check your console to make sure that the params are getting passed.   If your form object is a new order: `form_for(@order)`, the params will be in `[:order][:here_is_the_param]`
You’ll probably want to use strong parameters... (continued in next comment)

Comment: `def order_params

    params.require(:order).permit(:shipping_street, :shipping_city) 

end`

Keep in mind that the `require(:order)` will vary depending on your form object.  

You access the params like `order_params[:shipping_street]`

Without strong parameters you’d access the parameters like `params[:order][:shipping_street]`

If you need more help, post your view/form code and also the parameters that your console outputs when completing the form submit action.